# Сколько с в слове искусственный камень

Tags: орфография, грамматика

Сколько букв **С** правильно писать в слове "искусственный" во втором случае - при написании словосочетания "искусственный камень", где искусственный понимается как "ненатуральный"?

Answer (score 1):

Слова искусный, искусство,  искусственный требуют к себе определенного внимания:

В указанных словах можно выделить историческую приставку ИС и корень КУС; соответственно, удвоения СС  на стыке приставки и корня не происходит.

Прилагательное ИСКУСНЫЙ заимствовано из старославянского языка, где оно является префиксальным производным от глагола  кусити со значением «испытывать, пробовать» –  заимствование из германских языков. Изменение значения слова происходило по схеме: пробовать → проба, попытка →  умение, знание → умелый, искусный.

Существительное ИСКУССТВО также заимствовано из старославянского языка и является производным от искус –  испытание, проба, попытка. Удвоение СС в слове искусство происходит на стыке корня КУС и  суффикса СТВ.

Прилагательное ИСУССТВЕННЫЙ образуется ОТ ИСКУССТВО с помощью суффикса ЕНН.

Все слова являются МНОГОЗНАЧНЫМИ (но написание не зависит от значения):

искусный –  1) умелый, хорошо знающий свое дело (искусный мастер);  2) хорошо сделанный (искусная работа);

искусство –  1) отражение действительности   в   художественных   образах (направления в искусстве); 2) умение, мастерство (искусство художника, военное искусство);

искусственный – 1) не  природный, сделанный  наподобие  подлинного (искусственный алмаз); 
2) притворный, неискренний  (искусственное веселье).

Comment: откуда Вы позаимствовали сведения о германоязычном происхождении глагола "кусити"? Фасмер и Шанский таких версий не приводят.

Comment: Сведения взяты у Черных и основаны на исторической фонетике. И.-е корень  этого глагола -  geus (испытывать пробовать), сравнить: латинское  gustare и позднее русское заимствование "дегустация". О.-с. корень  kus  без германского (готского, точнее) влияния имел бы форму zus или  gus, сравнить (готск.) - kiusan - пробовать. В современном немецком языке die Kunst - искусство, künstliche - искусственный. В то же время этот вопрос не решается однозначно и требует дальнейших исследований.

Answer (score 0):

"Искусственный камень" от ИСКУССТВО - две "С": искус+ств.